# "em" inside of "strong" or the other way around?

Tags: html

Both of these would render the same thing:

1. `<strong><em>text</em></strong>`
2. `<em><strong>text</strong></em>`

Does one have an advantage over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO** advantage whatsoever as far as nesting is concerned

But these tags do have semantic meaning(also [@Reeno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952264/em-inside-of-strong-or-the-other-way-around/19952301#comment29695238_19952301) pointed out), also screen readers read the text wrapped between these tags at a higher voice... but the disadvantage is if you want your text to be normal you need to go around all pages and remove the tags manually.

---

Other way round is you can use CSS, and you can control the styling using a single class

```
p.emstrong {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2x6Xc/)

---

Also, these styles are often used `inline` so assigning `class` to `p` element won't make sense here, better use `span` tag with a `class` like

```
<p>Hello, <span class="emstrong">Style This</span></p>

span.emstrong {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: CSS is not always an alternative for these tags... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML

Comment: @Reeno I know they do have semantic meanings also screen readers read these text differently, OP questioned workarounds so I provided one

Answer (score 1):

No advantage at all em are used for formatted a text:

I can *not* emphasise this enough!

The HTML  tag is used for indicating strong importance for its contents. The strong tag surrounds the emphasized word/phrase.